# Using node-waves NPM package with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the node-waves NPM package with my Angular 2 project, but struggling and I can't find any examples out there to help me...

This is the package and library i'm trying to get working...

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-waves
>
> http://fian.my.id/Waves/

I've installed the package from NPM and am requiring and using it in my component as follows...

```
import {Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NavItem} from "../nav-item";
var Waves = require('node-waves');

@Component({
    selector: 'app-nav-item',
    templateUrl: './nav-item.component.html',
    styles: [ require('./nav-item.component.scss') ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})

export class NavItemComponent {

    @Input()
    item: NavItem;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        Waves.attach(el.nativeElement, null);

        var config = {
            duration: 500,
            delay: 200
        };

        Waves.init(config);
    }
}
```

The template for the above component is as follows, which gets generated within the `<app-nav-item></app-nav-item>` tags.

```
<li>
    <div id="testdiv" class="testclass">
        <a routerLink="{{item.href}}" routerLinkActive="active-link">
            <i class="fa fa-fw {{item.icon}}"></i>
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

The SCSS for the component...

```
@import "../../../scss/_color.scss";
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import "../../../../node_modules/node-waves/dist/waves.min.css";

li {

  div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      align-items: center;
      color: $primary-color-text;

      i {
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
      }

      span {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
    }

    a:hover {
      background-color: $accent-color;
      color: #212121;
    }
  }
}

.active-link {
  background-color: $accent-color-lighter;
  color: #212121;
}
```

Could anyone provide some insight into what I may be doing wrong, as the waves effect is not working when I click the `<app-nav-item>` element. Thanks (i'm pretty new)... :/

Comment: Are you getting any error? Do you see any errors from developer tools?

Comment: Nope no errors at all, that's why I'm lost as to what to do... I'm wondering has anyone been able to get the node-waves package working as part of an angular2 app using ViewEncapsulation.Native and Webpack2 for build?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think the place you are initialising is not in the correct place. You need to be hitting it after the components have been instantiated on the page which may be better in the afterviewinit event if you are going to use that method.

Alternatively I found that using the routing framework and capturing the navigationend event then calling the init event seems to work. That way you wont have to initialise in each component. A bit like this:

```js
constructor( private router: Router )
{
    router.events.subscribe( ( event: RouterEvent ) =>
    {
        if ( event instanceof NavigationEnd )
        {
            Waves.attach( '.btn', ['waves-float'] );
            Waves.attach( 'button', ['waves-float'] );
            Waves.init(); 
        } 
    } ); 
}
```